# Using a macro to create conditional formatting in Word as per Excel

Tags: vba, ms-word, conditional-statements

I have an Excel doc that has conditional formatting that changes the background colour of a cell, dependant upon the specific [dropdown] text that is selected. E.g Yes, changes cell background to Green, No to Red, Unknown to Yellow and Not applicable to Grey.

All easy stuff.

I then need to mailmerge to a Word doc to populate the Word doc with the Excel table - the Word doc also has other non-excel related text.

As conditional formatting of the cells does not come across, I have used the under noted code in a macro to change the background colour in Word. It runs, but seems after the first loop, it seems to crash with the error - `Runtime error 5907 - there is no table at this location`.

the line in the code `r.Cells(1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = backgroundColor` is highlighted yellow.

My level of coding is basic so I don't know what's going wrong.

If anyone is able to offer an insight to a simple solution, I would appreciate it.

Thank

```
Dim r As Range

Sub UBC()
    color "No", wdRed
    color "Yes", wdGreen
    color "Unknown", wdYellow
    color "Not Applicable", wdGray50
End Sub

Function color(text As String, backgroundColor As WdColorIndex)
    Set r = ActiveDocument.Range

    With r.Find
       Do While .Execute(FindText:=text, MatchWholeWord:=True, Forward:=True) = True
    r.Cells(1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = backgroundColor
       Loop
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible (likely) that Word is finding a character combination outside a table cell. Safest is to test whether the found term is actually *in* a table. (Note: I've also put the variable declaration `Dim r` inside the Function...)

```
Sub UBC()
    color "No", wdRed
    color "Yes", wdGreen
    color "Unknown", wdYellow
    color "Not Applicable", wdGray50
End Sub

Function color(text As String, backgroundColor As WdColorIndex)
    Dim r As Word.Range

    Set r = ActiveDocument.content

    With r.Find
       Do While .Execute(findText:=text, MatchWholeWord:=True, Forward:=True) = True
          If r.Tables.Count > 0 Then
            r.Cells(1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = backgroundColor
          End If
       Loop
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Provided you have a field in Excel that you can test for the colouring conditions, you don't need a macro for this. Instead, see Conditionally Shade Table Cells in the Mailmerge Tips and Tricks thread at: http://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html or: http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/163017-Word-Mailmerge-Tips-amp-Tricks

Comment: @macropod If you want the OP to see it, you should comment on the Question, itself, rather than my answer. Or "ping" the person using the @ symbol, as I did for your name. In this case, I got "pinged" automatically because you posted the comment to the Answer.